# How to convert float with integral value to integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have floats and some might have integral value, for example:

```
a = 1.0
b = 2.56
```

Now, I want to have:

```
a = 1
b = 2.56
```

How to convert only floats with integral value to integer?

Comment: `def round_if(a); a.to_i == a ? a.to_i : a; end` then `round_if(1.0) #=> 1`, `round_if(2.56) #=> 2.56`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Input

```
a=12.0
```

Code

```
a = a.to_s
     .split('.')
     .last
     .to_i > 0 ? a.to_f : a.to_i
```

Output

```
12
```

Comment: This will fail for large numbers where `Float#to_s` returns the exponential form, e.g. `1.2e+15`.

Comment: And also for small numbers like `0.00001`